# How to design API using Insomnia which asks for token and refresh token as a header?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, insomnia

I'm new to OpenApi and Swagger Ui,I tried Using this but this gives me a response as unable to login and the request Url is correct so I don't understand what i'm doing wrong and i tried using postman with the same url and in the header i'm passing Authorization:{"token":"TOKEN","refreshToken":"REFRESHTOKEN"} it works there:

```
parameters:
    - in: header
      name: Authorization
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              token:
                type: token
                example: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYwNTFiNGE0MmJhZGI0MTlkZTA5MDRhZiIsImVtYWlsIjoic2hpdmFteWFkYXYucy5rLnlAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiZXhwaXJ5RGF0ZSI6IjIwMjEtMDktMjhUMDA6MDA6MDAuMDAwWiIsInByb3RvY29sIjpmYWxzZSwicGxhblR5cGUiOiJwYWlkIiwidHlwZSI6MSwiY3VycmVudFZlcnNpb24iOiIwLjIuOSIsImJldGFWZXJzaW9uIjoiMC4yLjkiLCJpYXQiOjE2MjU0ODE2MjQsImV4cCI6MTYyNTQ4MzQyNH0.p1KmZkxbieH6lWr6JURbHgHBpkJngJYzlrHOMEWAbXk"
              refreshToken:
                type: token
                example: "5PrWmJyxheJ4hUY2bEHsZBtXRcJhY7v7I4jb9PmwxL9zaMgF8FalWatnl5YOT316y9IiQFzUsBDWyFay6tTR3vP6USaz0DqZ9l0obLGMCP8nmGhMvDQwTaZXGMXqisDy"
      required: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Header parameters named Accept, Content-Type and Authorization are not allowed. [check this doc](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#header-parameters)